# How do I select a value from a hidden select list?

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, html-select, watir

I want to select the hidden select list from [this website](https://werkenbijaegon.nl/vacatures/?utm_source=aegon.nl&utm_medium=link&utm_content=home&utm_campaign=werkenbij) and select the option `0 - 0,5`.

I keep getting a `(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)`.

The full error log:

```
/Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"2","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Host":"127.0.0.1:8910","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{}","postRaw":"{}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/115feff0-0b40-11e4-a69f-e39c52da2b2d/element/%3Awdc%3A1405333055513/click"}} (ReqHand) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:369:in `clickElement'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in `click'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/select.rb:155:in `select_by_string'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/select.rb:131:in `select_by'
        from /Users/#/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/select.rb:64:in `select'
        from aegon.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

This is what the HTML of the select list looks like :

```
<select name="werkervaring" class="selectBox" style="display: none;">
   <option value="">Geen voorkeur</option>
   <option value="1">0 - 0,5</option>
   <option value="2">0,5 - 1</option>
   <option value="3">1 - 2</option>
   <option value="4">2 - 5</option>
   <option value="5">5 - 10</option>
   <option value="6">&gt; 10</option>
</select>
```

note the `style="display: none;"` is the reason I keep getting the error.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
b.goto('https://werkenbijaegon.nl/vacatures/?utm_source=aegon.nl&utm_medium=link&utm_content=home&utm_campaign=werkenbij')

b.select_list(:name => 'werkervaring').select '0 - 0,5'

b.close
```

The questions is how can I select the option `0 - 0,5` from a hidden select list? Should I use something else instead of Watir?

Comment: Short Answer: If user can't, Selenium can't.

Comment: A user can. The hidden select list is somehow connected to the visible and styled one. Take a look at the html. If I select `0 - 0,5` via the visible one, the hidden one changes as well and does all the work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watir-webdriver - Select a list display style: none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391437/watir-webdriver-select-a-list-display-style-none)

Comment: If there's a visible and styled element, why not interact with that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after the select list there is a link and in that link is the down arrow of the select_list. After clicking the arrow, there are uls and lis. There is an li with the value you are looking for. In there is a link. Click on it.

```
b.select_list(:name, 'werkervaring').parent.link.click
b.li(text: '0 - 0,5').link.click
```

Note, to assure we are using the correct list, I still used werkervaring as a unique locator, then found the sibling link under the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium only allows interactions a user can achieve, therefore does not allow interaction with a hidden list.

If the list appears upon some action (e.g mouse over) then you need to perform that action first.  If the list is exposed via another object (e.g select2), then you must interact via that element.

however, if you really want to achieve this without following this, then you could execute JavaScript via selenium to enable or set it.

The merits if testing this way are debateable though

Answer (score 0):

```
b.select_lists[2].select "0 - 0,5"
```

Comment: Locating the select list by index does not change whether or not Watir can interact with it. Regardless of how you locate it, the select list will still not visible. Therefore Watir/Selenium will not allow you to interact with it.

Comment: Say what you want, this worked for me. I was able to manipulate everything in the form.